# MATCH with optional graph parts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph model consisting of two node types. Each USER has a dependency to one or more USERs via a DEPDATA node (which holds significant information on the relationship).

```
(:USER)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:DEPDATA)-[:FOR]->(:USER)
```

This chain can have infinite length, so the part

```
-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:DEPDATA)-[:FOR]->(:USER)
```

can be repeated n times. It's also possible that a USER has no relationships, so this all is valid

```
(:USER)
(:USER)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:DEPDATA)-[:FOR]->(:USER)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:DEPDATA)-[:FOR]->(:USER)
```

What I like to retrieve is all USER nodes which depend on a specific USER node, regardless in wich depth.

I've already read about variable relationship length here http://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html but it seems to apply only for direct relations.

How can I make a whole part of the graph structure to be matched 0..n times?

Comment: Why are you storing the 'significant information' in a specific node, and not on the relationship directly? If you were, you could use a var-length relationship.

Comment: AFAIK I can store only simple datatypes in relationships, not my own complex java classes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Nodes and relationships support the same property values. Which version of Neo4j are you on?

Comment: The 'significant information' is some kind of subtree, in this example information about the kind of dependency and rules for evaluating the dependency, consisting of one to n nodes each also interconnected by relations. I'm using spring-data 4.1.4.RELEASE with neo4j-ogm-core 2.0.5.

Comment: I see. I assumed you were on 'pure' Neo4j, but was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `n` as your upper bound, but you said the chain could be infinite length. In this situation, if you are not applying an upper bound, then you don't need to have a variable for it.

I think what you're looking for is something like this (using ID property as a placeholder for however you're uniquely identifying the dependent User node):

```
MATCH (dep:User{ID:123})<-[:DEPENDS_ON|FOR*0..]-(u:User)
RETURN DISTINCT u
```

This will match on zero or more chains of :DEPENDS_ON or :FOR relationships, finding all distinct dependent users.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this does match the requirements. USER and DEPDATA are two different node types and the variable part of the graph is a relation via each of them "-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:DEPDATA)-[:FOR]->(:USER)". I don't see how DEPDATA is taken in account here.

Comment: The thing about matching on variable relationships is that the intermediate nodes in the path won't matter. This match will return any :User node that is reachable by traversing :DEPENDS_ON and :FOR relationships, it doesn't matter that there are :DEPDATA nodes (or any other nodes of any other label) along that path. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results for each "full" path starting at the "root" node in a separate collection, the following should work. (A "full" path is one that has the root node at one end and a "leaf" node at the other.)

```
MATCH p=(u:USER)-[:DEPENDS_ON|FOR*0..]->(root:USER {id: 111})
WHERE NOT ()-[:FOR]->(u)
RETURN [n IN NODES(p) WHERE n:USER] AS path_nodes;
```